# How to force one specific series to ignore Stops coloring in Highcharts Solid Gauges chart

Tags: highcharts, gauge

Is it somehow possible to force one specific series ignore solid gauges Stops? In example below I would like series RMPX (second one) won't be orange but gray instead.

```
 yAxis: {
    stops: [
        [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
        [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
      ]
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DuFuS/35vx9rpy/

Answer (score 2):

There is no such API option out of the box, but you can easily extend Highcahrts to achieve this. Here is the example wrap:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.solidgauge.prototype, 'drawPoints', function(p) {
    let ret = p.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    let series = this;
    if (series.options.ignoreStops) {
      series.points.forEach(point => {
        if (point.graphic) {
          var color = series.options.fillColor;
          if (color !== 'none') {
            point.graphic.css({
              fill: color
            });
          }
        }
      })
    }
    return ret;
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

Include property to the series config and define color:

```
series: [{
    ignoreStops: true,
    fillColor: 'grey',
    ...
}]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uxL7zqtc/

More about extending Highcahrts:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts